# Upgraded from dotnet 5 to 6, getting error when decrypting: The computed authentication tag did not match the input authentication tag

Tags: .net-core, encryption

I upgraded from dotnet 5 to 6, and I'm unable to decrypt data that was encrypted before the upgrade:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The computed authentication tag did not match the input authentication tag.
   at System.Security.Cryptography.AeadCommon.Decrypt(SafeKeyHandle keyHandle, ReadOnlySpan`1 nonce, ReadOnlySpan`1 associatedData, ReadOnlySpan`1 ciphertext, ReadOnlySpan`1 tag, Span`1 plaintext, Boolean clearPlaintextOnFailure)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.AesGcm.Decrypt(ReadOnlySpan`1 nonce, ReadOnlySpan`1 ciphertext, ReadOnlySpan`1 tag, Span`1 plaintext, ReadOnlySpan`1 associatedData)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Managed.AesGcmAuthenticatedEncryptor.Decrypt(ArraySegment`1 ciphertext, ArraySegment`1 additionalAuthenticatedData)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, UnprotectStatus& status)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Unprotect(Byte[] protectedData)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.DataProtectionCommonExtensions.Unprotect(IDataProtector protector, String protectedData)
```

Does this mean I'll need to re-ecrypt encrypted data, or is there some way I can configure my IDataProtector to be backward compatible?

In my startup, I register my DataProtector like so:

```
var config = new AuthenticatedEncryptorConfiguration {
  EncryptionAlgorithm = EncryptionAlgorithm.AES_256_GCM,
  ValidationAlgorithm = ValidationAlgorithm.HMACSHA256
};
var credentials = new AzureCliCredential(new AzureCliCredentialOptions {
  TenantId = "<tenant id guid>"
});
var dataProtection = services
  .AddDataProtection()
  .PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(new Uri(azureStorageSettings.KeysFullBlobUri), credentials)
  .UseCryptographicAlgorithms(config)
  .ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault(new Uri(azureKeyVaultSettings.KeyUri), credentials);
```

And when here's what I use to encrypt/decrypt:

```
private readonly IDataProtectionProvider _protectorProvider;

...

public string EncryptFormSubmission(string formSubmissionJson, string itemKey)
  => GetProtector(itemKey).Protect(formSubmissionJson);

public string DecryptFormSubmission(string formSubmissionJson, string itemKey)
  => GetProtector(itemKey).Unprotect(formSubmissionJson);

private IDataProtector GetProtector(string itemKey)
  => _protectorProvider.CreateProtector(_coreSettings.FormSubmissionKey + "_" + itemKey);
```

I'm starting to look through https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/DataProtection/DataProtection/src/Managed/AesGcmAuthenticatedEncryptor.cs, so I'll update if I find anything out.

Comment: You should post your encryption and decryption code and some test data.

Comment: Good call, I updated to include the relevant code.

Comment: Crap, I forgot test data. I'll see about getting that as well as a simple console app that can be run.

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly set the app descriminator to what it had been before. In my case, my code was running on an Azure App Service instance, so it was using `"D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot"`, which is what it gets set to by default if none is provided in that scenario.

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Internal.HostingApplicationDiscriminator` uses `_hostEnvironment.ContentRootPath` as the value for app discriminator if none is provided in both dotnet@5 and dotnet@6. BUT dotnet6's `_hostEnvironment.ContentRootPath` has a slash on the end, whereas dotnet@5 didn't. i.e. it is set to `D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\`.

So:

```
services.AddDataProtection(o => o.ApplicationDiscriminator = "D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot")
```